# How to transform XML into HTML using XSL?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to transform an xml document into html using XSLTProcessor.

My xml document is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <property title="title1"><![CDATA[data1]]></property>
        <property title="title2"><![CDATA[data3]]></property>
        <property title="title3"><![CDATA[data3]]></property>
        </item>
        <item>
        <property title="title4"><![CDATA[data4]]></property>
        <property title="title5"><![CDATA[data5]]></property>
        <property title="title6"><![CDATA[data6]]></property>
        </item>
</items>
```

What i have to get is:

```
<html>
    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#eee"><td colspan="2">title1: data1</td></tr>
                <tr><td> title2</td> <td>data2</td></tr>
        <tr><td> title3</td> <td>data3</td></tr> 

        <tr bgcolor="#eee"><td colspan="2">title4: data4</td></tr>
                <tr><td> title5</td> <td>data5</td></tr>
        <tr><td> title6</td> <td>data6</td></tr>


    </table>
</html>
```

My xsl file now is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items"/>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">

    <tr bgcolor="#eee"> <td colspan="2">
        <xsl:value-of select="/descendant::*/@*"/>:
        <xsl:value-of select="property"/>
        </td> </tr>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it returns only first tag "property". I am new in xslt, what have i do to get list of "property" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used templates fine at the beginning, just continue to do that, writing templates and applying them:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="items"/>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="items">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item/property[1]">

    <tr bgcolor="#eee"> <td colspan="2">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>:
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td> </tr>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item/property[not(position() = 1)]">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `for-each` statement

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:for-each select = "property">
    <tr bgcolor="#eee"> 
      <td colspan="2">
        <xsl:value-of select="/descendant-or-self::*/@*"/>:
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I also changed your `descendant` to `descendant-or-self` to be exactly equivalent to what you had before.

Comment: Thanks, it works too, but use "<xsl:for-each" seems not a good practiceююю